# Customized list form vs javascript & html solution in SP2010

Tags: javascript, spservices, list-form

I have one requirement in which we have to enter the q1,q2,q3,q4 details for 3 consecutive years for three categories, that means total 36 fields. There are some other fields similar to this. So total we have found out 150 fields.

Client want to enter the details with some validations along with some calculations. For this what i have used JavaScript solution. I have created one HTML file and JavaScript file by using `SPServices`. I am embedding this HTML file in content editor web part. Because of this solution number of fields was reduced to 50. But client is saying we don't accept this because no one knows JavaScript,

if any thing need to change we have to approach some other developer. All they want is create 150 columns in the list form. So when ever user clicks on any `AddNewItem` then our custom form will get load with 150 fields with some UI changes. 
But now the questions are:

1. Is Customizing a list form a better solution than the JavaScript solution with SPServices?
2. If we customize the list form with 150 fields is there any chance that list form may corrupt? Because if any thing goes wrong we have to design the form from scratch again.
3. If JavaScript solution is better than list form customization then how to convince client.

Comment: You lead off that you have 1 requirement - but there are quite a bit more in a project like this and you need to really understand what those are if you are going to be successful.

Answer (score 0):

You have some qualitative question there - hard to give a definitive answer.  The first place I would start is going back and being sure you really understand what the requirements are in full.  You need both the technical and business requirements, and should understand what they are using this form for.  Then you can help them understand the benefits of each approach as well as the short comings.  It may be as simple as just providing some instruction on how to make changes they anticipate needing down the road.

Some technical stuff;
It seems your solution is already working with the number and types of columns you need for data storage (you are not exceeding the byte or row limit) - which is a good start.

As far as list form objects, if you use out of the box and user credentials to access data then you will be restricted to the throttle limits available.  So if you have 12 different lookup columns (which include people) then you will problems with your views.  Developers have a higher limit when access data via API calls (if allowed - which is by default).  You also are limited in the way you can do things like populate drop downs and there is type ahead functionality in these forms.

If you have some UI changes to the form, you may be using JavaScript anyway to make that happen. If you don't want to use JavaScript - then you will most likely be building custom ASPX pages in the backed - so if they don't have .NET knowledge they are in the same boat.

Comment: There are no lookups or anything. all are simple single line of texts and some dropdowns and one people picker control. Custom aspx forms not allowed, no .net based solutions. Any solution should be client side.